# EditText text selection popup has wrong theme on Android 6.0 only

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-6.0-marshmallow

While I was using the **Material components** for **Android** (https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) I was forced to inherit my application theme from "MaterialComponent" instead of the classic "Theme.AppCompat" in order to make the material components work. While I was testing the application with the integrated material components, on **Android 6.x.x** Marshmallow I observed that there is is a strange theme for the popup items when I select a text in any of my EditTexts.

Here is an example with the actual Material theme

[image: cut, copy, paste etc. are all separate colored buttons]

and here is the expected theme

[image: cut, copy, paste etc. are all black text on a white bar]

Has anyone encountered the same issue before?